# Plotting multiple lines in Matlab - make colors more intense on each iteration?

Tags: matlab

I am plotting graphs of a function that changes slightly on each iteration as it converges towards its limiting values...How can I make the colors of the lines get more intense on each iteration? By intense I mean the lines stay the same color but get more saturated or darker on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are plotting all you lines with one call of `plot` then set the `'ColorOrder'` property of your [axes (search for ColorOrder)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html).

If you are using a loop, then you could do something like this:

```
baseColour = rgb2hsv([1,0,0]); %// Get the HSV values for pure red, but choose any colour
hue = baseColour(1);
saturation = baseColour(2);
for k = 1:n
    %// do stuff
    lineColour = hsv2rgb([hue, saturation, 1-(k-1)/(n-1)]);
    %plot(..., 'Color', lineColour)
end
```

This should shift your lines from having no lightness (value actually) i.e. black to being fully light, but keeping the same hue and saturation which creates a fairly natural colour grading. This makes the most sense if your data are ordinal i.e. the user should know that the value of some property of the data forming the bright lines is greater than the value of that property of the data froming the darker lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own colormap, and for a given color you can set the intensity by interpolating the rgb values while keeping the proportions - an example explains what I mean more clearly. So for green:

```
cmap = [zeros(128,1), linspace(0,1,128)', zeros(128,1)];
imagesc(1:128)
colormap(cmap)
```